# Mysql queries running slow after initializing a Master-Slave Replication

Tags: mysql, locking, replication

SQL queries are running slow after re-initializing a Master slave replication MYSQL 5.7.
I had to reinitialize the replication ( backup and restore from master to slave and configured replication again) due to lag issues.  SQL queries were running fine before this activity but it is taking more than 10 to 12 hours to execute since the day I did this activity.
Master - On premise Mysql.
Slave -  Azure VM Mysql.
The SQl queries are executed on the Slave.

The SQL query consist of 16 select statements with Union. When the select queries are executed individually they give results but when executed along with a union it runs for 12 hours and times out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: More DB information request from on premise MASTER, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck  Thanks for responding. RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Do you need these details from the Master server or the Slave ( I am facing the query slowness issue in slave)

Comment: @WilsonHauck Also, I made configuration changes to VM where the MYSQL is hosted and the replication is in sync now but the one particular query takes a more than 12 hours to execute.  Earlier this used to take 15 mins.   information_schema.innodb_trx  does not show any blocking or waits.  Any help regarding this will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need data from on-premise MASTER, please.  AND another set of data from SLAVE, please.

Comment: We also need the complete QUERY that runs on the SLAVE for 12 hours and times out, along with EXPLAIN SELECT (your 12 hout query).

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thanks for the response. This is resolved. The issue was with the IOPS. I increased the IOPS on the VM disks.